# How to make the script check all "item__sizes" for the number of child elements and replace parameters

Tags: javascript

I need the script to find all "item__sizes" elements and count the number of child elements. If there are 2, then the width of "item__checker" = 50%. If 1, then the width of "item__checker" = 100%.

#### HTML (PHP)

```
<?php if ($product_attributes): ?>
    <div id="item__sizes" class="item__sizes">
        <?php $is_first_item = true; ?>
        <?php foreach ($product_attributes as $attribute): ?>
            <?php
            $attribute_active_class = $is_first_item ? ' active' : '';
            ?>
            <button class="item__size js-item__sizes_btn js-btn-product-attribute<?php echo $attribute_active_class; ?>"
                data-product-attribute-price="<?php echo $attribute['price']; ?>"
                data-product-attribute-value="<?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>" type="button"><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></button>
            <?php
            $is_first_item = false;
        endforeach;
        ?>
        <div class="item__checker"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### JavaScript

```
const checkWidth = () => {
  const numberOfBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('.item__sizes').childElementCount;
  const checker = document.querySelector('.item__checker');
  if (numberOfBtns === 2) {
     checker.style.width = "50%";
  }

  if(numberOfBtns === 1) {
     checker.style.width = "100%";
  };

};
checkWidth();
```

Comment: what is the buttonLength value? Could you provide your HTML? I tested it with what I think your HTML looks like and it worked for me

Comment: again, your code worked for me (the previous one, not this new one), can you try to provide more info on what the values of the variables are?

Comment: code that initially worked but only for 1 object, I can't get the script to work for all objects on the page

Comment: oh, ok. You should have said that earlier. I'm going to edit my answer to solve that issue

Comment: I've updated my anser, tell me if it works now

Comment: Everything works as I wanted, thank you very much))

Comment: I think you are new here, when an answer solves your issue you should accept it, that way the person who posted the answer gets a little reputation boost, and if you like any answer you can upvote it, as a way of demonstrating it's a good answer, not wanting to pressure you into anything lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are only selecting one of your item__sizes to do the test. You need to loop through all of them:

```
(function() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.item__sizes');

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        var buttonLength = buttons[i].querySelectorAll('.item__size').length;

        var checker = buttons[i].querySelector('.item__checker');

        if (buttonLength === 2) {
            checker.style.width = "50%";
        }
        if (buttonLength === 1) {
            checker.style.width = "100%";
        }
    }
})()
```